# Eclipse not able to see javax package

Tags: java, eclipse, java-16

I'm currently trying to fiddle with images, specifically convert images from JPEG, WEBP, and BMP forms to PNG forms and my method uses the `javax.imageio.ImageIO` class. When I tried importing it, Eclipse yelled that the package that the type was not accessible. I thought that was weird and went digging through StackOverflow on my own and found multiple answers saying I should remove and re-add the JRE. This didn't work, somewhat unsurprisingly, but while looking through my build path I noticed that the JRE was missing the entire javax package. Is there a reason this could be? Is there a fix?

The exact error reads `The type javax.imageio.ImageIO is not accessible` and the suggested edits ask me if I want to make class `ImageIO` in package `javax.imageio`.

I am using the latest build of Eclipse. My JDK is `java-16-openjdk-amd64`. I am running Ubuntu 20.04. I built this app from the ground up, so I am not using Maven (unless Eclipse uses Maven by default).

I tried compiling a basic class in my command line and it worked for some reason, despite not working in Eclipse.

I would rather not revert my JDK to an older version if I don't have to.

Comment: Is `javax.imagio.ImageIO` a typo in your question?  The package is [javax.imageio](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) (notice the `e`).

Comment: #1 Is your app using maven? #2 Could you share us a screenshot of eclipse error? #3 Could you build and run it with oure shell to validate if it is an error in your code?

Comment: Are you using a `module-info.java` file in the same package as your class?

Comment: Are you using modules?

Comment: @nitind the `module-info.java` belongs into the root of the source directory, not into the package.

Comment: Even without modules, Eclipse supports restricting the APIs the code of a project can use, but this is unlikely to get configured without the developer knowing. Can you see the class in the Package Explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was being just being an idiot. It turns out I had actually made this with a module without realizing it. All it took for me was to get rid of the module file.

Answer (score -3):

You do not call "new" on a **static class**
To make an instance non static of it if it ever does have such a type available from one of its static methods you cast it to that type.
However, with the javax.imageio.ImageIO `you make other classes from its methods`.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
try{  // wrap in FileNotFoundException  IOException

File input = new File("/somewhere/over/the/rainbow/cementplant.jpg");
//static classes are called directly with a method
BufferedImage bfi = (BufferedImage)javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(input);
```

Comment: I never said I was making new ImageIO objects. I am not making new ImageIO objects.

Comment: You seem to be confused what static classes are in Java, because you definitely can (and depending on the context, should) new them. Whether or not you use new doesn't depend on whether or not a class is static, but whether or not its constructor is accessible to your code. Also, `ImageIO` is not even a static class.

Comment: While every static class is loaded by the machine as new, there is only one copy. static classes also are encapsulated in an OUTER class that sometimes is able to be called as new but NEVER a static class (except maybe perhaps in how to load the inner static class with reflection but that last remains a choice of the interpretation by the JVM of the reflection methods). No they are not called with "new".